# Why is IEnumerable the recommended datatype for iterable lists when indexing is considerably slower than normal arrays or Lists in C#?

Tags: c#, performance, .net-core, types, c#-4.0

I've only been learning C# for a couple of months now (new job). I ran a crude speed test on some of the looping patterns and something caught my eye.

```
int[] myArr = new int[] { 11, 12, 13, 14, 6, 22, 45, 13 };
IEnumerable<int> myEnum = myArr;

DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
int enumSum = myEnum.Sum();
Console.WriteLine("time using IEnum.Sum(): " + (DateTime.Now - start).TotalSeconds);
Console.WriteLine("using IEnum.Sum(): " + enumSum);
```

On the average, the while and foreach loops perform far better than their counterparts (when I manipulate the array directly).

```
while (idx < myArr.Length)
{
    total += myArr[idx];
    idx++;
}
Console.WriteLine("time using while loop: " + (DateTime.Now - start).TotalSeconds);
Console.WriteLine("using while loop: " + total);
```

However, as IEnumerable indexes cannot be referenced directly, I tried using the ElementAt() method and the difference was incredible.

```
while (idx < myEnum.Count())
{
    total += myEnum.ElementAt(idx);
    idx++;
}
Console.WriteLine("time using while loop: " + (DateTime.Now - start).TotalSeconds);
Console.WriteLine("using while loop: " + total);
```

Using Builtin IEnumerable.Sum(): **time using IEnum.Sum(): 0.005396**

Looping through the array directly: **time using while loop: 4E-07**

Looping through the IEnumerable: **time using while loop: 0.0011301**

I understand that IEnumerable has a ToArray() method, but really want to understand why IEnumerable is the preferred way of representing iterable data/lists in C# if it is quite considerable slower to iterate/loop through than other types.

Comment: `while (idx < myEnum.Count())` is not how you are supposed to iterate over an `IEnumerable<T>`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1532814/5133585) for how you are supposed to do it. You can also see why your way is bad by reading the comments under Alexa Adrian's answer there.

Comment: Accessing sequentially via an index is *not* how enumerables are typically consumed. If *that is your use case and performance bottleneck*, don't pick enumerable. But you'd be in an exceptionally niche area of usage. Also, there are many pitfalls to fall into when measuring performance and I'd advise you look at e.g. [benchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet) if you want to do proper benchmarking.

Comment: `Count()` and `ElementAt()` are both enumerating operations when the source isn't an IList or IReadOnlyList. So you have nested O(n) algorithms which are exponentially slower by nature. If you'd just enumerate the enumerable in foreach it'd be as fast as the indexdased operation.

Comment: One of the caveats of home-made DIY benchmarks: [C# takes more time to do first execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28950581/c-sharp-takes-more-time-to-do-first-execution).

Comment: One of the core ideas in OOP is for your methods to declare parameters using the most narrow interface possible. If you only need to iterate through elements, you will use an `IEnumerable<T>`. If your method requires indexing, but doesn't need to change the collection, use an `IReadOnlyList<T>`. If your method needs to add or remove elements, use an `IList<T>`. You can still pass a `List<T>` as all of these parameters, but you can rest assured that the method accepting `IEnumerable<T>` won't modify your data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, your benchmark is just not accurate enough to do any conclusion. At the very least you should use a [stopwatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=net-7.0), and I would highly recommend using [benchmark.Net](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet), since that compensates for many easy to make mistakes when benchmarking.

Second, you should rarely, if ever, use `.ElementAt`. You use an `IEnumerable` when you need to iterate over all the items, but do not need indexing. Usually by using a `foreach`-loop, but you can also get the enumerator and do a `while(enumerator.MoveNext() {enumerator.Current}`-loop if you really need to. If you *do* need indexing, use a [IReadOnlyList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ireadonlylist-1?view=net-7.0).

But even then a for-loop over an array or list will be faster than a foreach loop over an ienumerable. This is because IEnumerable is more abstract, and that abstraction has some cost in performance. This idea that abstraction has a cost appears in many situations in programming. Ideally the compiler would be able to optimize away this cost, but that is not always possible.

In practice the performance difference between an `IEnumerable` and list/array will be irrelevant for the vast majority of cases. Computers are fast, and most lists are fairly small. If you *do* have huge arrays, say images with millions of pixels, then you should likely try to stick to lower level constructs, like arrays, `Span<T>`, pointers, for-loops etc.